# How do I find out whether my hard disk is connected via USB-2 or USB-3?

Tags: linux, usb-drive

My system disk is an external USB device that does not show up here (it is a 240GB San  disk).

```
➤ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 005: ID 05ac:8242 Apple, Inc. Built-in IR Receiver
Bus 004 Device 008: ID 05ac:828a Apple, Inc. 
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Blueto
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 0424:2512 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 174c:5106 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1051 SATA 3Gb/s bridge
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:0408 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd USB Keyboard
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 4e53:5407  USB OPTICAL MOUSE 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 004: ID 08bb:2912 Texas Instruments PCM2912A Audio Codec
Bus 005 Device 006: ID 256c:006e  
Bus 005 Device 005: ID 046d:09a6 Logitech, Inc. QuickCam Vision Pro
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 0424:2504 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 04e8:5f06 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Samsung STORY Station
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Maybe it is the one empty line?
However, what  interests me, is, whether it is being accessed as a USB-3 disk. How could I test that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a directory dedicated to every usb devices under `sys`.

For example, on my system i have a camera at `Bus 001, Device 002`:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:5686 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
```

I can find detailled informations under `/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-2` (where the last path components are bus id and device id as mentioned aboved).

Then i can dump the effective bus speed for this device and many others informations:

```
.../usb/devices/1-2$ cat speed  
480
.../usb/devices/1-2$ cat serial 
0001
.../usb/devices/1-2$ cat product 
Integrated_Webcam_HD
.../usb/devices/1-2$ cat configuration 
USB Camera
.../usb/devices/1-2$
```

So, for your issue, you may search on sub-directory `5-6` to check if it is your flash drive...
Also to identify your device, you may:

```
lsusb > with_device
# unplug device
lsusb > without_device
diff without_device with_device
```

IMHO, i would check this device:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 174c:5106 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1051 SATA 3Gb/s bridge
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot! Quite illuminating!

Comment: Device id seems to be 0-based, so Bus 002 Device 004 translates to 2-3:1.0 here, there is no device @ 2-4.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
lsusb -t
```

The USB speed is at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Because USB 3 SuperSpeed and higher use physically different wires in the USB cables, the higher-speed USB3+ wiring is usually presented in Linux as a completely separate USB bus.

As a result, the presence of a "Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub" marks the SuperSpeed-capable USB buses - in your case, `Bus 003` and `Bus 006`. And since there are no other devices present on those buses, I must conclude that all your USB devices are currently using USB 2 speeds only.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. Do you know, if the mentioning of two Linux Foundation 3.0 root hubs means, that they are actually present, or could they just be placeholders? There is no USB Plug empty on my system, so at least something would have to be connected to such a hub, I suppose.

Comment: Look carefully at your USB sockets - the SuperSpeed-capable USB A sockets have five square contacts at the "tip of the tongue" in the socket. A SuperSpeed-capable USB A plug has five corresponding contacts "deep in the throat" of the plug. A SuperSpeed capable device connected with a cable that has corresponding extra connectors should use those contacts in preference over the regular USB2 contacts.